# Xcode debugger: cmd line application - start with sudo?

Tags: xcode, macos

I need to debug a command line application with Xcode... 
and I need to have the debugger launch my app with 'sudo'.
How do I tell Xcode to do that?

thx->adv

Comment: Have u tried adding a new custom executable with sudo as the target and your program as an argument.
I haven't tried it but i think it will work.
Hope it helps

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Have you tried starting Xcode with sudo?
The processes it spawns (gdb,...) should also run with superuser privileges:

```
sudo /Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/MacOS/Xcode
```

Comment: please see answer from @Frank instead of running all of Xcode as root

Answer (score 20):

Running XCode as root is a bad idea.

There is an option for this in XCode (6.2):

- Product -> Scheme -> Edit Scheme
- Select the "Run" configuration
- Change the radio button for "Debug Process As" to "root"

Answer (score 1):

You could launch XCode itself with `sudo`, then it will be running with the privileges of your nominated user, and also your application would run with the same privileges.

This may not be the best way; there may be a way to tell XCode to launch your application in a particular way. But the above method will work in any case.